# Vue.js simple script don't work

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, vue.js

I'm trying to run the code bellow, which is probably the most simple example of Vue.js, but it doesn't work at all:

```
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>
<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
</script>
```

What's the problem? I'm loading `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>` in the header, no errors or warnings in Chrome dev tools. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: replace your script with that: <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>  and let me know if it is working

Comment: @MU still don't work. I tried to use ```<script src="unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>```, it's redirected to the https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js with code 302

Comment: Where do you load the script? JSfiddle works fine with this vue link https://jsfiddle.net/2cjsr81q/

Can you post the content of your main html ?

Comment: post your complete html file as Cristi asked

Comment: @MU Here's a source code https://gist.github.com/pavlovdog/112e361f8a582578f2b3217a5e87678b

Comment: This code should work perfecly, I tested it on my machine - it display up the correct message Hello Vue! - the thing that is broken is the font awesome cdn url, so maybe for some reason it makes the problem.
Also consider about moving js files to bottom, just before `</body>`

Comment: @BelminBedak still don't work :C Here's a link, check it out http://104.131.12.118:4949/ . I'm running exactly this code on Digital Ocean + Flask, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turned out, that Vue.js and Flask are using the same syntax for templates (two handelbars `{{}}`). So if you're using both of them - check this out https://github.com/yymm/flask-vuejs